# Define reitit route segment as matching string or dynamic param as fallback

Tags: api, clojure, reitit

I am defining a nested router with reitit and I want to create a v2 of the api. Currently the api is attached at `/something/` and I have routes defined for `/something/<long-id>` so when I try to add a route for `/something/v2` it gets matched as if v2 is an id. I have tried putting the definition for v2 first in the router definition in the hope it will be matched first, but it does not match.

```
(ring/router
  [["/v2/:part1/:part2" { :conflicting true }
    ["" { :get {:handler some-handler-v2}}]]
   ["/:part1/:part2" { :conflicting }
    ["" { :get {:handler some-handler}}]]
  ])
```

How can I configure reitit to understand that if the path segment is v2 use one config, and if it's anything else, use the other config?